# params return null in axios post method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net, typescript, axios

I have a simple code as below, but the productArray in axios always returns null.

It works when I do it with jquery. what am i missing?

```
$.post(`/api/${productId}/getProducts`, { products: productArray })
```

###### My Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetProducts(int productId, Request request)
```

###### My class

```
public class Request 
{
public List<ProductDetails> Products { get; set; }
}

public class ProductDetails
{
public int ProductId { get; set; }
public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

###### axios

```
async function GetAllProducts() {
    let productArray = [];
    productArray.push({ productId: "1",  price: "5" });
    const response = await axios.post(`/api/${productId}/getProducts`, productArray)
}
```

Comment: given the proposed answer, @lovida5233 still having trouble?

Answer (score 0):

The "thing" you are sending with jQuery is an object that contains a single key/value pair of `products: productArray` but what you are sending in axios is only the `productArray`, not the object containing the array. if you create the object and send that, your axios call would match your jQuery call

```
async function GetAllProducts() {
    let productArray = [];
    productArray.push({ productId: "1",  price: "5" });
    let o = { products: productArray };
    const response = await axios.post(`/api/${productId}/getProducts`, o)
}
```